# How can I prove or disprove that both limits here do not exist?

Tags: limits, proof-writing

I would like to prove or disprove that $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}f(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}g(x)$ both do not exist.

I know that $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and functions $f,g$ are both defined at least on $[a,\infty)$, and that $\forall x≥a$, $f(x),g(x)≠0$. I also know that $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}[f(x)-g(x)]$ does not exist but that $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}[f(x) \times g(x)]$ exists.

My thinking is as follows:
If both limits exist, then $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}f(x) - \lim\limits_{x \to \infty}g(x)$ must exist as well. Since we know that this does not exist, then at least one of the two limits cannot exist. However, if one does not exist, I don't understand how $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}f(x) \times \lim\limits_{x \to \infty}g(x)$ can exist.
Am I in the right direction? What am I not understanding?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Writing down examples seems like a natural place to start.

Comment: Consider $f(x)=1/x²$ and $g(x)=x$, as well as $a>0$. - Show that those would follow your assumptions and what these would do wrt. your claim.

Comment: Something to start with: If the limits $\lim _{x\to \infty} f$, $\lim _{x\to \infty} g$ exist and are reals then also $\lim _{x\to \infty}(f-h) $ would exist..

Comment: @dmtri by (f-h) did you mean (f-g)

Comment: @lulu you're absolutely right, my apologies, edited

Comment: @liatkatz, yes sorry, it was a typo.

Comment: Why on earth was this question closed?

Comment: Take $f(x)=\sin x +2$,  $g(x) =\frac{1} {x} $, in order to see an example of what can happen, namely that $\lim fg$ can exist.

Answer (score 2):

If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)$ both exist, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)g(x)$ also exists, and is equal to the product of the two limits.

The converse is only partly true: if $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)g(x)$ exists, and one of $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)$ exists *and is non-zero*, then the other limit also exists.

For example, if $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=1/x$ on $[1,\infty)$, then the limit of the product exists (and is equal to $1$), but $f(x)$ does not tend to a limit. This is possible because $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=0$.

Comment: Although not clarified in the question, the limits may be also $- \infty, + \infty$, so the first line of your nice answer may include the case $0 \cdot \infty$

Comment: @dmtri: I hope the OP isn't as confused as I am by your comment!